# AngularJs and SocketIo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I need some help understanding the code below. It is taken from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
```

I am having problem understanding:

1. From where did `arguments` come
2. what is callback.apply and what is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic JavaScript, nothing to do with AngularJS or Socket.io.

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is a "magic" variable available inside every function to access it's arguments in array-like manner.

[`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is a way to call a function with a different `this` context providing `arguments` as the second argument.

Comment: Controller is this:
`function AppCtrl($scope, socket) {

  socket.on('init', function (data) {
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.users = data.users;
  });`

Can you explain me the flow? I am not sure what `callback.apply` is invoking.

Comment: I believe the post answers your initial questions (if you agree, you can accept it). If you have more questions, feel free to create more posts.